# What means a "$\setminus$" logic symbol?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a task to calculate a double integral on a region $D=A\setminus B$, where $A=\{(x,y): \text{some  
system of inequalities}\}, B= \{(x,y): \text{another system of inequalities}\}$. What does operator "$\setminus$" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the set difference operator. $A\setminus B=\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\}$.

For example $\{0,1\}\setminus\{1\}=\{0\}$. And $\Bbb Z\setminus\Bbb N$ is the set of negative numbers. $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is the set of irrational numbers, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

"$\,A\setminus B\;$" $\,$ means the $A$ "set minus" $B$: that is, it defines a region which contains all points $(x, y)$ such that $\,(x, y) \in A,\,$ but $\,(x, y) \notin B$.

$$A\setminus B = \{ (x, y)\mid (x, y) \in A \land (x, y) \notin B\}.$$

In your case, the region $A\setminus B$ means "all points satisfying the system of inequalities defining set $A$, but **not** satisfying the system of inequalities defining set $B$.