# Mathematical symbol is "relative compliment"?

Tags: notation, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

A bit of a dumb question, but it's blocking my work at the moment so I'm hoping it will be tolerated !

I have a research paper describing an approach to Convex Quadratic problems (D. GoldFarb and A. Idnani 20 Oct. 1981).

Unfortunately it's a scanned copy (I bought online and downloaded) and I cannot quite read one of the symbols for sure (I am not an expert on this sort of maths).

I wander if anyone can confirm if this symbol is "Relative compliment" ? Which is what I suspect. I have circled the symbol in red:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What means a "$\setminus$" logic symbol?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494343/what-means-a-setminus-logic-symbol)

Comment: What you mean is a [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)), not a [compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compliment)

Comment: My question wasn't what does the symbol "Complement" mean, my question was related to the symbol in the paper which looked like it might have been a ">" misprinted.

Comment: That symbol is $\setminus$ and its meaning is explained in the link from my first comment.

Comment: Thanks. It's been very helpful to get and experienced answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the idea is that in b case A becomes smaller and smaller (hence K-A becomes bigger and bigger) until all constraints are satisfied (a case)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the complement of a set is written with the symbol $\setminus$ :

$$B\setminus A=\{x \in B| x \not\in A\}.$$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) for details.